# Google Translate API Error "Unable to perform Translation:Please use Translate v2. See http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html"

Tags: php, api, google-translate

I am using GTranslate from google I already follow the steps create account and use the api key but I got confused in this part. Anyone?

Comment: You are using translate v1 and its telling you to use v2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using deprecated API.

Google was closed the free version of translator and requested users to switch to paid Version by 2011.

[Details Here](http://www.gts-translation.com/blog/2011/12/06/google-translate-api-casualties/)

And [Here](https://developers.google.com/translate/) google officially announced it.

*Google Translate API is available as a paid service. See the Pricing and FAQ pages for details.*